# MTLLoader doesn't show texture on the object I load

Tags: three.js, objloader, mtl-file

I'm new to ThreeJS, still learning. I have like an earth globe 3d object that I load into my scene, and I also have a mtl file which I load according to the documentation, but after I render the scene the globe still looks without texture. I think it only shows the geometry.

Tried loading the globe in Blender and the texture looks good in there, but in browser things aren't the same.

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.load('/models/Glob.mtl', function(materials) {
materials.preload();

var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
objLoader.load('/models/Glob.obj', function(object){

    scene.add(object);
    console.log(object);
});
```

});

I'd like to find a way to show the texture of the globe so I could move on with my project.

Comment: The error is probably from your material file. Are you using any image?

Comment: No, this is the content of the mtl file:

newmtl wire_204204204
 Ns 32
 d 1
 Tr 0
 Tf 1 1 1
 illum 2
 Ka 0.8000 0.8000 0.8000
 Kd 0.8000 0.8000 0.8000
 Ks 0.3500 0.3500 0.3500

newmtl wire_088144225
 Ns 32
 d 1
 Tr 0
 Tf 1 1 1
 illum 2
 Ka 0.3451 0.5647 0.8824
 Kd 0.3451 0.5647 0.8824
 Ks 0.3500 0.3500 0.3500

Comment: The thing is that in Blender looks okay...

Comment: yes, but Blender isn't Three.js ;) When you export your files, are all the following elements checked (see image file here https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/resources/images/windmill-export-options.jpg) ?